# nodejs instead of localhost showing other URL

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

Everyone, I am new on nodejs and struggling with an issue, I have created a basic nodejs app and i have added `PORT=5000` `HOSTNAME=localhost` in my .env file.

And in my index file, I have added

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || 'localhost';

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

But when I am running app it's showing in the console as **http://Abhishek:5000/**
Please help me out to understand the issue and how I can solve it.

Comment: Is something loading this `.env` file?

Comment: Also, as a best practice, use the server's `address()` method to figure out what it's actually listening on, rather than relying on the variables you set.  While it should match, sometimes you might get surprised.  https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_address

Comment: @Brad thanks for your reply. But what are the possibilities and where i can check for changes?